# Ubuntu Touch on Nexus5x

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-5x

I don't see references to the 5x specifically and don't know if the Nexus 5 image would work equally well on a 5x. Issues of Ubuntu support for the Nexus 5 aside, has anyone successfully installed Ubuntu on a 5x? And/or can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* install the Nexus 5 image on your Nexus 5x. Those devices are fundamentally different and you won't end up with a usable system (you might even soft- or hard-brick your device). There's no completed Ubuntu Touch port for the Nexus 5x yet, and it's not being worked on at the moment. That being said, after the move to [Halium](https://www.halium.org) that situation might change.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same, and found this:

https://wiki.ubports.com/wiki/Nexus-5X-Developer-Information

Since Ubuntu Touch is dead, the guys from UBPorts seems to be giving a try on porting it to Nexus 5x. The challenge is due to the fact that it ships with Android 6, compared to Android 5 from Nexus 5.